# How to make this image visible

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

This is the soil moisture data that I downloaded from the NASA website. When viewing the geotiff file in QGIS I'm getting this black and white picture only. I know that there's some adjustment I need to make in the raster properties but can not figure out how to do. I've just started with QGIS and don't know much about it yet.

When I open this file in QGIS it looks something like the black and white image:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Open styling panel (F7) and try different setting, for example under "Contrast enhancement" and "Min / Max Value Settings"

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!